# Jenkins marked build as failure, although all test case passed for iOS app

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild

I am using Jenkins job for running current test cases for iOS app. using,

```
xcodebuild test ... | xcpretty
```

Although all tests are successful but Jenkins still marked build as failure.

How can I see the actual result?

[image]

#### Edit-1:

Even when i removed `| xcpretty`, still jobs marked as failure. Here are the full shell command,

```
xcodebuild test -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme App -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6, OS=10.2'
```

Comment: Are you using Jenkins pipelines?

Comment: yes i am using xcodebuild with xcpretty.

Comment: Please show the failing shell script.

Comment: see edited question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was solved by placing below line at the very begining of jenkins shell

`#!/bin/sh`

Comment: I know this is over a year old, but where can I add this? I don't know how to access this from Xcode Integration